# Pegar o id do textview que é inserido na listview e colocar no bd

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Tenho um layout com 2 listas, uma complementa a outra, **categoria** e **subcategoria** gostaria de, quando fosse inserir uma subcategoria ao clicar em adicionar alimentasse a database com o id da categoria que está na mesma linha, ou seja, vou ligar uma categoria a uma subcategoria.

Por enquanto o app está adicionando uma subcategoria a todas as categorias, pois não consegui ainda resolver isto.

[image: Exemplo de categoria e subcategoria]

Exemplo, quando eu clicasse para adicionar uma subcategoria (botão "+" ao lado da categoria) abrisse um dialog pra inserção do nome da subcategoria (já tenho pronto) e ao clicar pra adicionar ele ligasse o id da categoria que estava na mesma linha do botão (na imagem a linha Aquisições) e inserisse na chave idcategoria que tem na tabela subcategoria.

Aqui está o layout, é um linear com um edittext, um botão e uma lista, que dentro dela tem outra lista onde vão as subclasses

[image: Lista Categorias][image: Lista SubCategorias]

Código que insere a Subcategoria - **CategoriaAdapter**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final int auxPosition = position;

    Categoria categoria = new Categoria();



    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.categoria_row,null);

    final TextView categ = (TextView)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.tvCat);
    categ.setText(lista.get(position).getNome());



    final ImageButton button = (ImageButton)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.btAddSubCat);
    button.setTag(categoria.getId());

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alert.setTitle("Adicionar subcategoria");
            alert.setMessage("Digite um nome para a subcategoria:");

            final EditText input = new EditText(context);
            alert.setView(input);


            alert.setPositiveButton("Adicionar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    int idCategoria = (Integer) button.getTag();

                    subcategoria.setNome(input.getText().toString());
                    subcategoria.setIdCategoria(idCategoria);


                    SubCategoriaDAO subCategoriaDAO = new SubCategoriaDAO(context);

                    subCategoriaDAO.inserir(subcategoria);
                }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    return;
                }
            });

            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Onde está o código mostrando até onde você fez?

Comment: Você tem que explicar esse layout. Está confuso.

Comment: Não adianta jogar uma imagem e sair pedindo pra gente ajudar nisso ou naquilo.

Comment: @Rafael, tem razão, é uma layout com 2 listas, 2 adapters, vou colocar imagens e o código que faz adicionar a subclasse.

Answer (score 1):

Simples!

Você precisa adicionar no botão '+' o id da categoria através do método `setTag(...)` que é disponibilizada para qualquer componente visual que herde de `View`. Ou seja, quando o usuário clicar no botão, o listener responsável pelo evento de click irá passar como parâmetro a `View` clicada, nesse momento você executa um `getTag(...)` que irá retornar um `Object`, ai é só dar um cast para Integer e realizar o CRUD no banco de dados. :-)

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: no caso o método seria esse? 
final ImageButton button = (ImageButton)
                layout.findViewById(R.id.btAddSubCat);
button.setTag("idcategoria");
e como seria o cast pra pegar a id do textview? @FelipeBonezi

Comment: Você tem que trocar o "idcategoria" pelo número inteiro que identifica a categoria, e não uma String. Para o cast, é só fazer int idCategoria = (Integer) button.getTag();

Comment: Agora não está aparecendo a subcategoria, botei no debug está retornando a subcategoria corretamente, porém com idcategoria 0, deve ser por isso que não aparece na lista. @FelipeBonezi

Comment: Você passou o idCategoria no setTag()?

Comment: Passei sim @FelipeBonezi, olha o código lá na pergunta, acabei de atualizar.

Comment: @AllanChrystian você está instanciando uma Categoria para cada view criado no getView, não pode! O seu adapter tem que receber uma Lista de Categorias populaça, e no getView você chama o método getItem do adapter para retornar a Categoria! Como é que você quer ter o id da categoria se quando você dá um new Categoria() o valor do id é inicializado com valor 0???

Comment: Entendi o que você quis dizer @FelipeBonezi, mas como farei isto? essa parte eu não entendi, pode me explicar? Tem alguma parde do código correta?